# Redirecionar Datatable js después de editar un registro Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, update

Estoy haciendo un crud básico, implementé Datatabels js para el listado, mi duda es que si por ejemplo tengo 20 registros y en la paginación me aparecen 2, cómo sería en el caso de que editará un registro de la segunda página y después de terminar de editar me redireccionara al listado en la página 2 donde está originalmente el registro, porque originalmente si edito un registro que se encuentra en la página 3 al dar guardar la edición de registro me manda a la pagina 1 de la JStable. Para el proyecto estoy usando Django

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No has aportado tu código para saber qué has intentado realmente, pero si haces uso de api de datatables, entonces tienes la opción de mantener el estado del datatables durante un reload: `table.ajax.reload( null, false );` el primer argumento es una función como callback, que puedes o no indicarla, y el segundo agurmento garantiza que el datatables mantenga su estado incluyendo la página seleccionada. En la configuración del datatable, pásale como argumento la propiedad `"stateSave": true`

Comment: se resolvió con stateSave, gracias